# How do I determine the row number of the row the function is executed in? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, function

How do I find out the row the function is executed in? Just an example:

```
Function getRowNumber () as Integer
     getRowNumber = ???
End Function
```

I need this because I wrote a function that is supposed to return values from the same row (formular gets its own column and then calculates more than 300 different values for these 300+ rows). Or is there another way how I address values in the row?

Comment: You don't need to write a function yourself since `=ROW()` will get what you are after.

Comment: But I need input for Row, what I dont have. The solution below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Application.Caller` property in this case. Something like the following may help you.

```
Function Tester() As Long
    Dim o As Object
    Set o = Application.Caller
    
    Tester = o.Row
End Function
```

Perhaps a more structured approach would be to take a `Range` as a parameter to your function, and then use the row of that input parameter.

```
Function Tester(rng as Range) as Long
    Dim nRow as long

    nRow = rng.Row 
    'Do other stuff
End function
```

Comment: @BigBen I edited my post for `Long`. My takeaway from his post was that this was part of a bigger function call, and he wasn't actually writing a `UDF` to get the current row. I might be wrong, but that's how I interpreted it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for!